# Query date range AND time range in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, geofire

I would like to query my data set for results that occur within a date range and location range (geohash range). I am struggling to find a good solution.

I am using GeoFire and have tried various methods of segrigating my data either by date or location. It's easy enough to build a node for each day and plop geohashes inside but how can i then page through that data without downloading all 5000 results in the city of NYC for example?

If i could sort first on the geohash and then on the date this would be easily achieved but i can not do that in firebase or any NoSQL database.

Someone must have encountered this multirange query problem and i hope you can share what you learned.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> It's easy enough to build a node for each day and plop geohashes inside but how can i then page through that data without downloading all 5000 results in the city of NYC for example?

Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting your question. Would you be able construct a DatabaseReference to the node representing a specific day, creating a GeoFire object and a GeoQuery, repeating for each day?

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/dayNode");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6); // Use this for addGeoQueryEventListener() or something else
// See https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java
```

This would allow you to only download the locations in the 0.6 km surrounding 37.7832, -122.4056. To prevent downloading too many results at once, start with a small radius and increase from there?

As a side note, I believe Firebase Firestore allows for multiple cursor conditions such as:

```
db.collection("locations")
    .orderBy("locationhash")
    .orderBy("date")
    .startAt(locationHash, startDate)
    .limit(25);
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you would be able to specify a radius while sorting by date and paginating unless you extended the work done in GeoFire or GeoFirestore. Hopefully someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Yes, i have tried segregating the geohash data by day. My radius is 20 miles. I would like to avoid additional queries beyond whats needed to paginate.